# Calling a function only once

Tags: javascript

I have function like below, If I call my function `refreshPrice()`, it starts an ajax request and after 10 seconds again calls the function refresh the price.

```
 function refreshPrice() {

     var url = "example.com/refresh.php";
     $.get(url, function(data) {

         pricetimeout = setTimeout(function() {
             refreshPrice()
         }, 10000);

     })

 }
```

Problem is I call `refreshPrice()` again to immediately to call ajax.. there is multiple `refreshPrice()` function gets called.

```
clearTimeout(pricetimeout);
```

What actually need is pricetimeout should be called only on first time and it should be run every 10 seconds , I dont want setinterval(I get problem if pages are in background with seinterval)

From second time only ajax request without timeout should be done.

Comment: What you want is probably to "call n seconds after" using a promise completion

Comment: The alternative to Mark's suggestion is to schedule it with `setInterval` and use a (global) flag to indicate if the `$.get()` should be called.

Comment: Be aware that `setInterval` can run into race conditions - for example if you set a 3 second interval and it takes 5 to return you might start to stack up requests - so you might  do a "setTimeout" AFTER the promise is fulfilled - say make the next call 5 seconds after the prior one completes

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss : exactly   , I have explained that in my edit , can you explain more about your approach , I am not able to understand.

Comment: @Graciewilliams What do you want to happen if the `$.get` does not return a result within the time T? Do you want to wait indefinitely until it returns a result and make no more requests until then; forget about that call and do $.get again after T; or forget about that call an make another request T after the previous request? Do the requests need to be aligned to intervals of T, or intervals with T between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass flag to eliminate timeout second time

```
     function refreshPrice(flag) {

       var url = "example.com/refresh.php";
       $.get(url, function(data) {
         if(flag){
           pricetimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            refreshPrice(false)
           }, 10000);
         } else {
           refreshPrice(false);
         }
       })

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since I used jQuery, but [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) assure me that the return value of `$.get` is `Promise` compatible, meaning that you don't need to supply a callback and can, instead, `await` its result.

This means you should be able use `async/await` to make an `async` loop, something like this (untested):

```
const delay = (delayMs) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), delayMs));

async function refreshPrice() {
   var url = "example.com/refresh.php";
   while(true){
      const data = await $.get(url);
      // do something with data
      await delay(10000);
   }
}

refreshPrice(); // fire-and-forget this unawaited promise
```

This has the benefit that the timeout wait occurs **between** network calls, so if the network is slow, things won't start overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using an `async` function, just as below.

```js
 async function refreshPrice() {
   var url = "example.com/refresh.php";
   $.get(url, yourCallback);
   
  //wait for 10s before calling refresh price again
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10 * 1000));
  refreshPrice();
 }
```

This will work, instead of yours which is telling the browser to recall the `refreshPrice` function after a response is received. So if you are receiving a response after 1s, your function will be called after 1s.

Answer (score 1):

I have NOT tested this but this should give you a starting point (this was really really rapidly put together)

```js
var myRefresher = myRefresher || {
  url: "example.com/refresh.php",
  waitTime: 10000,
  shouldStop: false,
  handleRefresh: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (!myRefresher.shouldStop) {
        $(document).trigger('dopricerefresh');
      }
    }, myRefresher.waitTime);
  },
  doNewRefresh: function() {
    myRefresher.refreshPrice().then(myRefresher.handleRefresh);
  },
  refreshPrice: function() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: someUrl,
        data: {},
        xhrFields: {
          withCredentials: true
        }
      })
      .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("success");
        // do what you need here
      })
      .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // handle your error
        myRefresher.shouldStop = false; //stop trying
      })
      // read doc for parameters
      // .always(function(data or jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR or errorThrown) {
      // done and/or fail next thing
      // })
      // combines done/fail, see reference page
      .then(handleRefresh // gets passed data, textStatus, jqXHR 
        ,
        function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}) // fail in then
  }
};
// start the cycle
$(document)
  .on('dopricerefresh', myRefresher.handleRefresh)
  .trigger('dopricerefresh');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```